# Elasticsearch Exclude documents which does not match a criteria

Tags: elasticsearch

user_profile index has branches mapping with a propery country_iso

```
{
          "_index": "user_profile",
          "_type": "user",
          "_id": "188",
          "_score": 1.0042034,
          "_source": {
            "user_id": 188,
            "phone": "971550000322",
            "profile_set_date": "Apr 6, 2017",
            "phone_country": "AE",
            "branches": [
              {
                "id": 27,
                "brand_id": 20,
                "country_iso": "KW",
                "city_iso": "KW-02-145162",
                "area_id": 33
              },
              {
                "id": 45,
                "brand_id": 56,
                "country_iso": "AE",
                "city_iso": "AE-01-206944",
                "area_id": 18
              },
              {
                "id": 46,
                "brand_id": 56,
                "country_iso": "AE",
                "city_iso": "AE-01-206944",
                "area_id": 18
              }
            ],
            "prog_id": 13,
            "email": "971550000322@email.com"
          }
        }
```

I need to find the users who has branches mapping with country_iso=AE and not with anything else

must and must_not combination did not work for me

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "prog_id": 13
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": [
              "branches"
            ],
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "branches.country_iso"
                ],
                "query": "AE"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 1,
      "must_not": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": [
                    "branches"
                  ],
                  "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                      "fields": [
                        "branches.country_iso"
                      ],
                      "query": "AE"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. This one worked for me (notice the `negated` text search in the `must_not` statement):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "prog_id": 13
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": [
              "branches"
            ],
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "branches.country_iso"
                ],
                "query": "AE"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": [
              "branches"
            ],
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "branches.country_iso"
                ],
                "query": "-AE"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to be perfect. I will verify the resutl with more testing.